# Curl dentro de for demorado e com problemas

Tags: php, libcurl, for

Preciso de testar todas as contas de usuário de uma db no `text area`
estou `utilizando` o `script`

```
function informacoes(){
   $linhas = explode("\n", $_POST['conta']);
   $count = count($linhas) -1;

    for($i=0 ; $i<= $count; $i++) {
        $conta = explode("|", $linhas[$i]);

        $email = $conta[0];
        $senha = $conta[1];

        checker($email, $senha);
    }
}
```

Function checker :

```
function checker ($email, $senha) {
  // todo o sistema do curlopt esta aqui
  // exemplo
  if(strpos($data, 'Erro":false') !== false){
      echo "conta ativa";
  }
}
```

O `problema` é que fica `muito lerdo` e não funciona conforme o esperado.
Um outro `problema` também é que só `faz echo quando todas as contas já foram testadas`

Analise: caso o `text area` tiver apenas 1 conta o script é feito como esperado.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem, você quer verificar se as contas estão ok? **Ativas?** Se puder dê mais detalhes.

Comment: Então amigo, algumas contas é ativa e outras inativas. Quero que imprima as respostas.

Comment: Isso vai ser lento porque vai testar uma conta de cada vez, se você ainda recriar o `curl_init` vai ter que fazer todo a busca de dns, o handshake do https... Uma maneira talvez mais rápida, mas mais complexo e que usa mais recursos é utilizar o `curl_multi`, nele você poderia processar todos de uma vez só, ao menos as requisições podem ocorrer em paralelo, claro poderia processar em blocos.